# pagespeed on apache with nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, page-speed

I have a VPS and using the following stack:

NGINX as front-end proxy on port 80. Also port 443 for SSL
Apache on 8080 for dynamic content (mostly PHP)

Now, I want to use PageSpeed module by Google. On which of these to server I should install PageSpeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it passes through PageSpeed at least once, you will benefit from the optimization.

The flow is essentially the same, with a different order:

```
User <--- NGINX <--- PageSpeed <--- Apache
User <--- PageSpeed <--- NGINX <--- Apache
```

Some factors that could potentially sway your decision are:

- Has Apache been configured to use more resources, or has NGINX?

If one application has it's resources limited, and is placed under heavy load while also trying to call PageSpeed, it might have its performance impacted.

If you have specifically configured one application to be a heavier user of the system resources, you might want to attach PageSpeed's function to that application, so that it has more space to do processing and so on.